# Did i make my website responsive in a wrong way?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I got my html using bootstrap 3.3.7:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="copyright" content=""/>
        <meta name="author" contect="Toki, 2016/12/30"/>
        <title>toki</title>     
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/toki.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>     

    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <img class='bg' src='assets/media/main-bg.jpg'/>
                <div class='row'>
                    <img class='logo' src='assets/media/logo.png'/>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='main-content'>                  
                            <div class='downloadbox'>
                                <div class='downloadbtn'>
                                    <a href="#" class='iosdownload'></a>                
                                    <a href="#" class='androiddownload'></a>
                                </div>
                                <a href='#' class='call-btn'></a>
                            </div>          
                        </div>      
                    </div>      
                    <div class='row'>   
                        <div class='main-icon'>
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">Thông Tin game</a></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Tính Năng</a></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Nổi Bật</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                    <img src="assets/media/ts1.jpg"/>
                                    </div><!-- End Item -->

                                    <div class="item">
                                    <img src="assets/media/ts2.jpg">          
                                    </div><!-- End Item -->

                                    <div class="item">
                                    <img src="assets/media/ts3.jpg">
                                    </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                                </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/toki.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my css :

```
img.bg{ 
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-999999;

}

.logo{  
    z-index:1;
}
.header{
    text-align: left;
    height: 59px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(../media/menu_bg.jpg) repeat-x center center;
}

.main-header{
    position: relative;
}
.main-header > div{
    float:right;
}
.menu-cant{
    padding-right:350px;
}
.menu-game{
    padding-right:20px;
}
.dropdown-btn{
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    width: 139px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 18px; 
    background: url(../media/scol.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    padding: 4px 0 0 15px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top:8px;
    min-width:140px;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    line-height:11px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a{
    padding: 1px 12px;
}

.link-menu{
    display:inline;
    padding:20px 30px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.link-menu span {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 1px 0 0 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.fanpage-menu{
    background: url(../media/heart.jpg) no-repeat 0 center;
}
.fanpage-menu a{
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.user-menu{
    background: url(../media/user.jpg) no-repeat 0 center;
}

.logout-menu{
    background: url(../media/logout.jpg) no-repeat 0 center;
}

.login-menu{
    background: url(../media/login.jpg) no-repeat 0 center;
}
.new-menu{
    padding:30px 30px;
}

.new-menu ul{
    width:100px;
    list-style:none;
}

.dropdown-menu:before{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
.main-content{
    padding-top:300px;
    width:673px;
}
.downloadbox{
    background: url(../media/downloadbg2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 60px 0 0 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: -8px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;

}
.downloadbtn{
    width: 242px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 136px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.downloadbtn a{
    width: 242px;
    height: 55px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.iosdownload{
    background: url(../media/iosbtn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.androiddownload{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: url(../media/androidbtn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.call-btn{
    background: url(../media/monibtn_g.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 115px;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0 21px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}



.phone-box{ 
    padding:3px 0 15px 238px; 
    height:70px; 
    background:url(../media/phonebg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    margin-bottom:15px;
    min-width:700px;
}

.phone-box input.txt{ 
    width:300px; 
    height:40px; 
    padding: 0px 6px;
    line-height:40px; 
    border:none; 
    float:left; 
    display:inline;
    margin-top:13px;
}
.phone-box input.txt:focus{outline:none }
.phone-box input.submit{ 
    width:113px;
    height:40px; 
    border:none; 
    background:url(../media/submit.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
.main-icon{
    width:670px;
}



#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}

.carousel-inner{    
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.carousel-inner .item img{  
    padding:10px;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 320px){
  img.bg{   
    min-width: 640px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-999999;
    background-size:contain;
  }
}
```

I think my website is responsive one but my friend doesn't think that.
Did I do it wrongly?

Comment: Without attempting to run the page, I see no Bootstrap column (`.col-`) elements in your HTML. Do you understand Bootstrap and its responsive grid system?

Comment: then  if i add `col-` then  would it be responsive??

Comment: Guess that answers that. Start here to read about how to use Bootstrap's Grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: God jesus, you put a whole code in this ? LoL.. why won't you inspect all the element first and then show us the inspect with the mobile view website, so we can see what was happened with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're doing wrong in using Bootstrap.

Rows must be placed within a .container or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
So you can't put 'row' inside 'row'. You have to use 'col-md-12' as a child of row. for getting required layout.

Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Check the Bootstrap Doc for Grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think i would need to train myself more about responsive. I want to make my current site to be responsive one.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses a ***12-column grid system.*** The whole view port is divided into 12 equal columns,  which can be used individually or in a group. Their usage defines how your website will behave for different screen sizes. By default, Bootstrap allows four screen sizes which are ***xs, sm, md and lg.*** These have various pixel ranges. You have to use the columns according to the device screen specifications. 
The way to do that is by using the ***pre-defined class 'col'***. By appending .col along with screen specification and no of columns, you can define how a div will behave for that screen size. For example, .col-xs-12.col-sm-3.col-md-5.col-lg-7 implies that the div takes 12 columns on xs screen, 3 columns on sm screen, 5 columns on md screen, and 7 columns on lg screen. Also, if you don't mention the specification for a particular size, it assumes the same as it previous one. Hence all can be used together, or according to preference.

Go through this to get a better understanding of this grid layout : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/
Read the documentation here :
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.